# HTTPS connection awefully slow on windows mobile 6

Tags: web-services, ssl, windows-mobile-6.5

I am banging my head against the wall for about 3 days about this now.

We have implemented an application on a barcode scanner running Windows Mobile 6. The app accesses a database through a webservice hosted on an IIS using SSL encryption. After dealing with a win-mobile specific bug, not recognizing certificates correctly by adding my on CertificatePolicy this was working like a charm.

Now I have moved the webservice from my IIS to the ISS of my customer and establishing EVERY connection now takes about 4minutes(!). Its working perfectly fast on android devices, its working fast on any desktop browser, its is just not working on the scanner using windows mobile 6.

I tried to figure out what was so special about my IIS but I do not see it, except that it is using a certficate from another CA.

HTTP without encryption works fast on the scanner. HTTPS to every website i tried so far, takes bloody ages.

I do not see, on what to check next, support from the company selling the scanning device is slient, searched for 'windows mobile 6 ' with prases like 'very slow', 'ssl too slow', 'ssl connection not working' etc with no results.

I am spent, any help in this matter is greatly apreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the other CA cert as a trusted CA root and removing current CA as trusted because it may try to check for revoked certs and cannot contact your CA.

Hope this helps!